# Recursion, Common Term, Combinatorics

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

May we find the common term for recursive sequence? if yes that how to find the common term of recursive sequence such:  1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 6 ...

- in a pyramidal form:

  ```
                            4
                    3                3
                2        2       2       2
              1   1    1   1   1   1   1   1
  ```

Comment: It seems that the $n$-th term of your sequence is the largest $k$ such that $2^{k-1}$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good place where one can answer questions like this easily is the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, oeis.org .

Your sequence is https://oeis.org/A001511 .